# Can't get user email with the Viadeo API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

Hi i'm developing an application that once the user accepted to share his Viadeo informations, has to get the email. So i'm using the Viadeo API and coding in Javascript

My code is the following

```
VD.api('/me', {user_detail : 'partial'}, function(r) {
                        nom.value = r.last_name;
                        prenom.value = r.first_name;
                        presentation.value = r.introduction;
                        photo.value = r.picture_large;
                    });
```

In fact the r is a variable that is supposed to give me all the users informations (it's a JSON object.
I can't find email (even when I try with other options like "user_detail = full"

So my question is, Is it possible to retrieve the email of a user through Viadeo API?

Thks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I checked and we can't get the user email (for security against spam)

Comment: This is a shame it is not mentioned in Viadeo's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See this page, you should have all details regarding the api that you want to use

[Viadeo Dev Page](http://dev.viadeo.com/graph-api-resource/?resource=/user/)

As per this page, it seems you get the Member Id from the API. Just see that you are using the API in accordance with this page.